# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Ausbildung und Unterricht?

Tags: meaning, difference

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen Ausbildung und Unterricht? Haben sie die selbe Bedeutung? Kann man die beiden für die selbe Sätze benutzen?

Comment: Was sagt das eigene Wörterbuch dazu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ausbildung" is the whole process of being taught something. "Unterricht" is a lesson (or lessons) in something, normally with a teacher, and it's normally part of some kind of "Ausbildung".

Other parts of the "Ausbildung" can be tests, practicing, self-study etc. These are all not "Unterricht".

> Marvin macht eine Ausbildung zum Schreiner.
> Dazu gehören die Arbeit in einem Ausbildungsbetrieb und der Unterricht in einer Berufsschule.
> Um die neue Maschine bedienen zu können, braucht man eine spezielle Ausbildung.
> Die Ausbildung an einem deutschen Gymnasium bereitet auf ein Universitätsstudium vor.
> Kevin konnte dem Unterricht am Gymnasium anfangs schwer folgen, hat aber am Ende sein Abitur gemacht und beginnt jetzt eine Ausbildung zum Kraftfahrzeugmechatroniker.

Comment: "Ausbildung" is the whole process of learning something." No, it's the process of being taught something.

Comment: @Roland: Thanks, I agree, that's better. I'll edit.

Comment: Für mich steht da jetzt eine englische Antwort auf eine deutsche Frage ... Wäre es nicht eher üblich, die Antwort dann auch auf Deutsch zu schreiben?

Comment: Danke HalvarF für deine verständliche und detailreiche Antwort! Und Danke auch @Roland für deinen Beitrag!

Answer (score 2):

Nein, *Ausbildung* und *Unterricht* sind nicht immer synonym zu verwenden. Ausbildung bezieht sich oft auf die Berufsausbildung, während Unterricht meist für die Schule verwendet wird.

Beispiele:

- Der Schulunterricht beginnt um acht.
- Ich mache eine Ausbildung zum Tischler.

Comment: Man kann aber auch in der *Ausbildung* *Unterricht* haben, denn ein *Tischler* hat in seiner Ausbildung Schule, und somit wird er auch unterrichtet.

Comment: @SwissCodeMen Ja, das stimmt und bestätigt doch was ich geschrieben habe.

Comment: Man kann auch *Klavierunterricht* oder *Reitunterricht* ausserhalb der Schule haben. Unterricht hat nicht notwendigerweise etwas mit "Schule" zu tun.

Comment: @tofro Ja und man spricht dann auch oft von Reitschule oder Musikschule.

Comment: Danke Harald für deine Antwort! Und Danke auch @SwissCodeMen und tofro für deine Beiträge! –